# Probability of $f(n) - \varphi(n)$ to be an even number.

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $f(n)$ denotes the product of all the positive divisors of n, and $\varphi(n)$ denotes the sum of all the positive divisors of $n$. If number $n$ is to be randomly selected from the first $100$ positive integers, what is the probability that $f(n) - \varphi(n)$ is an even number?

So far, I know that $f(n)$ and $\varphi(n)$ need to be either both odd or both even. If $n$ is odd, then $f(n)$ must also be odd; if $n$ is even, then $f(n)$ must also be even. However, I have difficulty calculating when $\varphi(n)$ is odd or even. It appears to be completely random.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MSE. Although your title says you have no clue, please tell us what have your tried so far?  Here is a hint that might help you: The probability would be the # of values of $n$ where $f\left(n\right) - \phi\left(n\right)$ is even divided by the total # of values being checked, this being $100$ in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n)$ is odd whenever $n$ is odd and even whenever $n$ is even because when $n$ is even there is a factor $2$.

$\varphi(n)$ is multiplicative-we have $\varphi(nm)=\varphi(n)\varphi(m)$ whenever $n$ and $m$ are coprime.  If $n=p^k$ for $k$ an odd prime, $\varphi(p^k)$ is even when $k$ is odd, but $\varphi(2^k)$ is always odd.  This means that $\varphi(n)$ is even when $n$ has at least one factor of an odd prime raised to an odd power and odd otherwise.  For example, all multiples of $3$ that are not multiples of $9$ have an even sum of factors because we have all the factors without a factor $3$ and all the factors with a factor $3$, making $4$ times the sum of all the factors without a factor $3$.

For odd $n$ the only ones with $\varphi(n)$ odd are $9,25,49$, so $47$ odd numbers have $f(n)-\varphi(n) odd.

For even $n$ the only ones with $\varphi(n)$ odd are $18,36,54,72,90,50,80$ so $7$ even numbers have $f(n)-\varphi(n)$ odd.

The chance a number $n$ in the range $1$ to $100$ inclusive has $f(n)-\varphi(n)$ even is $\frac {51}{100}$

Comment: This is not right... Why is o(n) multiplicative? If you substitute 2 and 3 in, it is not right. o(2*3) ≠ o(2)*o(3)

Comment: @Chris:  yes it is.  $\varphi(2)=1+2=3, \varphi(3)=1+3=4, \varphi=1+2+3+6=12=3\cdot 4$